# python binary search with a function in a domain and limited iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary-search

I am busy with a binary search problem in Python.

This is the challenge

Challenge The binary search is considered to be a very powerful algorithm used for locating elements in an already ordered list. Its ability to halve the search space with every iteration is what makes it so efficient. With every iteration we are searching a smaller and more manageable subspace.

Over and above being able to locate items in a discrete list, it can also be applied on a continuous domain. For this question, you will be required to use the binary search to find the root of some function () on the domain ∈[,] by continuously bisecting the domain. In our case, the root of the function can be defined as the x-values where the function will return 0, i.e. ()=0 For example, for the function: ()=2()2−2 on the domain [0,2] , the root can be found at ≈1.43 .

Constraints

Stopping criteria: ||()||<0.0001 or you reach a maximum of 1000 iterations. Round your answer to two decimal places. Function specifications

Argument(s):

f (function) → mathematical expression in the form of a lambda function. domain (tuple) → the domain of the function given a set of two integers. MAX (int) → the maximum number of iterations that will be performed by the function. Return:

root (float) → return the root (rounded to two decimals) of the given function.

My code is as follows:

```
### START FUNCTION
def binary_search(f,domain, MAX = 1000):
    (start, end) = domain  # get the start and end point
    while start < end and MAX:

        # get the mid

        mid = (start + end) / 2.0

        # if we reached to root

        if abs(f(mid)) < 0.00000001:

            # return rounded

            return round(mid, 2)
        
        if f(mid) < 0:  # if we are left of root
            start = mid  # set start to mid
        else:

              # otherwise go to left

            end = mid

        MAX -= 1  # decrement max by 1

    return round(mid, 2)  # return rounded
### END FUNCTION
```

I am failing tests due to rounding, see below:

```
PASSED     binary_search
FAILED     binary_search
           Inputs: [<function <lambda> at 0x7f13d9a37d08>, (2, 3)]
           assert 2.0 == 2.56
           your output:     2.0
           expected output: 2.56
FAILED     binary_search
           Inputs: [<function <lambda> at 0x7f13d99be7b8>, (-2, -1)]
           assert -2.0 == -1.43
           your output:     -2.0
           expected output: -1.43
PASSED     binary_search
FAILED     binary_search
           Inputs: [<function <lambda> at 0x7f13d99be8c8>, (-2, -1)]
           assert -1.0 == -1.68
           your output:     -1.0
           expected output: -1.68
```

Example of test passing

```
binary_search(lambda x:(np.sin(x)**2)*(x**2)-2,(0,2))==1.43
```

I can not figure out how to correct this. Can anyone guide me on how to alter my solution?

Comment: You assume that the function is monotonically increasing, but that is not stated

Comment: Hi Matt

Thanks for your input, could you give me guidance on how to correct this?

Comment: Considering the introduction "already ordered list" I assume your function shall be monotonic, either increasing or decreasing. Hence, the case `f(mid) < 0` does not mean the same thing for one case or the other. Long story short, you should check if function is increasing or not (trivial at function entry...) and take advantage of that result for your `if` condition...
If your function is not assumed as monotonic, then the issue would get more complex to solve.

Comment: @Limtorak Where "more complex" simply means you replace `f` with `lambda x: -f(x)` when `f` is decreasing.

Comment: No, the "more complex" was in case function was not monotonic, not in case it was decreasing (which is as trivial as increasing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the bug:

```
        if f(mid) < 0:  # if we are left of root
            start = mid  # set start to mid
        else:

              # otherwise go to left

            end = mid
```

Here, the signs need to be checked before converging:

```
        if f(mid) < 0 :
            if f(start) < 0:
                start = mid 
            else: 
                end  = mid
        else:
            if f(start) > 0:
                start = mid 
            else : 
                end  = mid
```